Turn Specialized Crosstrail Disc 2014 into gravel bike
I am considering turning my Specialized Crosstrail Disc 2014 into a gravel bike.
I was somewhat following this post. But I decided to go with some other parts here and potentially higher total $$. I want to do everything myself, but I have 0 bike mechanics experience. There is good content on YouTube, and I'd rather invest in tools than pay local bike shop fat bill.
Here are the parts I have picked so far.
Crank: Shimano GRX FC-RX810 1x Crankset (compatible with wide range of Shimano 11t-40t cassettes)
https://www.backcountry.com/shimano-grx-fc-rx810-1x-crankset
https://velonut.com/blog/shimano-grx-2x-drivetrain-with-11-40t-cassette
https://www.cyclist.co.uk/in-depth/best-gravel-gearing-how-to-get-lower-gears
Cassette: Shimano Deore XT M8000 11-speed Cassette (11t-40t compatible with HG-11)
https://www.backcountry.com/shimano-xt-cs-m8000-cassette
Rear Derailleur: Shimano GRX RD-RX812 Rear Derailleur (11t-42t compatible)
https://www.backcountry.com/shimano-grx-rd-rx812-rear-derailleur
Bottom Bracket: Ultegra SM-BBR60 Bottom Bracket (English)
https://www.backcountry.com/shimano-ultegra-sm-bbr60-bottom-bracket
Tires: WTB Resolute TCS Tubeless Tire with SG2
https://www.backcountry.com/b/wtb-resolute-tcs-tire-tubeless
Wheels: WTB ST i23 700c Gravel 100mmx15mm 142mmx12mm Disc Wheelset fits Shimano 11spd  (https://www.randombikeparts.com/products/wtb-st-i23-700c-29er-100mmx15mm-142mmx12mm-disc-wheelset-fits-shimano-11spd-new)
Pedals: NASHBAR SOHO PEDALS (BLACK)
https://www.performancebike.com/nashbar-soho-pedals-black-ti-soho
Fork:
Suntour GVX LO R 700 (https://www.srsuntour.us/collections/forks/products/gvx-700c?variant=32147702022238) with headset adapter for 1-1/8" to 1.5" tapered forks FSA Orbit ITA 1 1/8" - 1.5" Tapered Headset (https://www.fsaproshop.com/products/orbit-ita-i-e-headset)
Few questions I have:

Did I miss any major specs of the components above, do you see something that won't be compatible together?
Do you have decent hydraulic breaks recommendation?
Do you have decent carbon bar and stem recommendation?
I believe there are rigid forks out there with some lighter profiles, but I would like to keep some suspension with my 1st gravel bike. I am excited that these adapters for tapered steerer tubes exist as I am reusing frame and the original fork is non-tapered 1-1/8". Do you see anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Welcome to Bicycles SE.  Too many questions at a time here.  Please split this up into separate questions.

You can’t turn a 1-1/8 headset into a 1.5 tapered headset. Any fork you buy will need to be 1-1/8 straight like the frame.
Do the wheels come with end cap adapters as your current forks and frame  seem to be for 10mm QR axles.

@WarrenBurton, I have watched couple of YouTubes where mechanics install tapered 1-1/8 to 1.5 fork using special headset: https://www.fsaproshop.com/products/orbit-ita-i-e-headset for the purpose. I wanted to still have suspension fork and not go rigid, but also to slim down some weight. Both fork and headset(adapter) arrived, but I don't have time until end of August to start working on this.

@azec-pdx there are almost no standards in cycling — except for tires (considering the formal definition standard, when you read "standards" in cycling, it means "manufacturer specifications"), it's not because there are videos on youtube that show that it is possible that the bike they used matches yours. Headsets are one of the messiest areas, 50mm headsets (like the one you linked) are common on MTBs and more recent bikes, but in the case of the crosstrail, the suspension/headtube alignment suggests that a smaller headset is used, so it's very likely that the headset you bought won't fit.

@azec-pdx that’s kind of cool. I’m not sure how that works to fit in the extra 3/8” of diameter inside the head tube. Maybe it keeps the widest diameter outside the head tube and the rest of the  taper fits inside. Nice find.

Product recommendations are off-topic here, but there are several points that are worth mentioning:

road and MTB standards are often different, so mixing the two is complicated.

Bottom brackets shell widths are different (road: 68mm, MTB: 73mm), so unless your bike has a 68mm shell, you won't be able to mount GRX components on a hybrid (it's now possible to find good 40T cranks for 73mm shells, in the CUES range for example).
brakes are mounted differently on MTBs and road bikes (you forgot them in the list, you'll need to change the calipers as well) so you'd need to use road/gravel levers with MTB calipers).
the compatibility with 11-speed is only important for road cassettes with large sprockets smaller than 32T included. If the large sprocket is larger than 32T, it will fit on a 10-speed freehub body any way.


such bike use standards that are considered to be outdated on mid range bikes.

you'll need wheels with quick release, not thru-axles. Some brands do offer end-adapters that allow you to choose one or the other.
the front suspension is not compatible, there are similar suspensions in the "trekking" ranges, it's also important to have the same amplitude for the suspension than the original one. Additionally, these forks are also cheaper for similar performance (no "gravel tax").



Quality tires are also a must, no matter the bike. But you need to have tires that match your usage. For offroad, tubeless is highly recommended.
And finally, I would also question the relevancy of the project. For context, I do have a similar bike that I upgraded and a proper gravel bike.
I thought the gravel bike could substitute the hybrid, but in practice it's not the case. With a carbon seat post and an well maintained air suspension, the hybrid is similar in comfort and is even more comfortable on rougher terrain (note that my gravel has a stem suspension with 20mm of travel and a very compliant carbon seat post), I added inner bar ends to have an additional hand position, that is also slightly more aero. On rougher offroad, I'm faster with the hybrid than with the gravel with the same tires (65mm suspension travel vs 20mm and flat bars allow for better control than drop bars). The only thing I miss on the hybrid are the drop position in head winds. On smoother terrain, the gravel has an edge (better aero and lighter ...but that wouldn't apply to converted hybrid anyway).
So in short, if you like offroad, converting your bike to a gravel won't give you any gain in offroad capabilities while upgrading it will. If you lean more towards road or smooth gravel, you'll probably end up with a bad compromise compared to a proper allroad/gravel, as you won't be able to compensate the shortages by changing components.

Thanks @Renaud. I appreciate all the feedback. I just received the book "Zinn & The Art Of Road Bike Maintenance (6th edition)". It covers gravel bikes as well. I am going to spend some time on it throughout August before I make orders for cassette, derailleurs, crank, shifters, and all break parts. I will try to update once I start "hands on" work.
